# iOS MDM Profile Installation Failed

Tags: ios, ssl, mdm

I tried the iOS MDM Protocol and got Profile Installtion Failed error. No other error message or reason was shown.

In the Certificate Payload, I set the Payload content to my root CA as a Base64 encoded string.

In the APNs Payload, I set the payload content to my apns certificate as a Base64 encoded string.

What are the possible reasons for Profile installation failure.

Comment: If you can show the profile that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why the mdm profile could have failed to install. It's very hard to pin point exactly what it is without seeing the profile. I don't have any actual sources, but rather from my own experience of working with mdm.

- You're trying to install a profile that is trying to check into a server but the server is down or you have no internet connection
- The profile was incorrectly created
- The profile has fields/keys that require the device to be supervised, but the device isn't supervised
- Your server is using a self-signed certificate and you don't have that certificate installed/coupled with the profile

etc. The list goes further than that to my guess.

Comment: Also, the check-in endpoint may have not responded appropriately